# How to get the Sum of Top N

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a List(Of ZZZ), (where ZZZ is a Class with a Cost and Week properties). I want to get the Sum of the Costs where the Week is in the top N of all the weeks in the List.

I have the following so far which gives me the total of all ZZZs

```
Imports System
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Collections.Generic
                
Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim MyZZZ As New List(Of ZZZ)
        Dim Total As Single
        Dim NumOfWeeksToSelect As Integer = 2
        
        MyZZZ.Add(New ZZZ With {.Cost = 1.1, .Week = 100})
        MyZZZ.Add(New ZZZ With {.Cost = 2.2, .Week = 100})
        MyZZZ.Add(New ZZZ With {.Cost = 3.3, .Week = 99})
        MyZZZ.Add(New ZZZ With {.Cost = 4.4, .Week = 99})
        MyZZZ.Add(New ZZZ With {.Cost = 5.5, .Week = 95})
        MyZZZ.Add(New ZZZ With {.Cost = 6.6, .Week = 95})
        MyZZZ.Add(New ZZZ With {.Cost = 7.7, .Week = 95})
        MyZZZ.Add(New ZZZ With {.Cost = 8.8, .Week = 90})
        MyZZZ.Add(New ZZZ With {.Cost = 9.9, .Week = 80})
        MyZZZ.Add(New ZZZ With {.Cost = 10.10, .Week = 70})
        
        Total = MyZZZ.Select(Function(T) T.Cost).Sum
                
        Console.WriteLine(Total)
    End Sub
    
    Private Class ZZZ
        Public Cost As Single
        Public Week As Integer
    End Class
End Module
```

How do I change the line `Total = MyZZZ.Select(Function(T) T.Cost).Sum` so that instead of all the items in the List, it just takes the items that have a Week that is in the top 2 of all the Weeks across all the items?

E.g. if NumOfWeeksToSelect = 2 then it will sum the first 4 entries in MyZZZ (because the first 2 weeks are 100 and 99). If it's 3 then it will sum the first 7 (because the first 3 weeks are 100, 99, and 95).

In addition I'd like to know how many weeks were actually selected. So if NumOfWeeksToSelect was 100, then the answer would be 6 as there are only actually 6 distinct weeks in the List.

The above is available here:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/SZrZUa

Also, I need this to run under .Net Framework v4 if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Dim total = (From obj In MyZZZ
             Order By obj.Week Descending
             Group By week = obj.Week
             Into weeks = Group
             Select week).Take(NumOfWeeksToSelect).Sum(Function(g) MyZZZ.Where(Function(obj) obj.Week = g).Select(Function(obj) obj.Cost).Sum())
```

What this does is:

1. Groups the objects by weeks
2. Takes the top N groups
3. Sum the costs of the top N group
4. Sum the total of number 3

Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/SeIw2q

Comment: Excellent, thanks. It's take me a few moments to full parse out what's happening, but I think I've got it. :)